# Can't load a model from an owl file which is in a jar file in Jena

Tags: java, jena

I am trying to load a owl-time model from an owl file which is an entry in my jar file, but it does not work. I'm doing something like:

```
        String path = "jar:file:/L:/WRK/Java/protobitbucket/jena/samples/JenaModule.jar!/org/da/protoframework/jena/owl-time.owl";
        OntModel owlTimeModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RDFS_INF);
        owlTimeModel.setNsPrefix("time", OWL_TIME + "#");
        FileManager.get().readModel(owlTimeModel, path);
        m.add(owlTimeModel);
```

And I have the following exception:

```
org.apache.jena.shared.NotFoundException: Not found: jar:file:/L:/WRK/Java/protobitbucket/jena/samples/JenaModule.jar!/org/da/protoframework/jena/owl-time.owl
at org.apache.jena.riot.adapters.AdapterFileManager.readModelWorker(AdapterFileManager.java:293)
at org.apache.jena.util.FileManager.readModel(FileManager.java:342)
at org.apache.jena.util.FileManager.readModel(FileManager.java:326)
```

I tried to use an IRI instead:

```
        IRIFactory factory = IRIFactory.iriImplementation();
        URI owlTimeURI = getClass().getResource("owl-time.owl").toURI();
        IRI iri = factory.construct(owlTimeURI);
        
        OntModel owlTimeModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RDFS_INF);
        owlTimeModel.setNsPrefix("time", OWL_TIME + "#");
        FileManager.get().readModel(owlTimeModel, iri.getFragment());
        m.add(owlTimeModel);
```

But this time I have this exception:

```
org.apache.jena.iri.impl.IRIImplException: <jar:file:/L:/WRK/Java/protobitbucket/jena/samples/owltime/../JenaModule.jar!/org/da/protoframework/jena/owl-time.owl> Code: 44/UNREGISTERED_IANA_SCHEME in SCHEME: The scheme name does not have a "-" in it, but is not in the IANA registry. (Last updated from the registry January 2006)
at org.apache.jena.iri.impl.AbsIRIFactoryImpl.throwAnyErrors(AbsIRIFactoryImpl.java:71)
at org.apache.jena.iri.impl.AbsIRIFactoryImpl.construct(AbsIRIFactoryImpl.java:66)
```

Whats's the correct way to load a model from an entry in a jar file in jena? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1:: Open an InputStream in plain Java:

If the jar file on the classpath, up an InputStream to resource in the file (standard java opertion). If it is not on the classpath, use the runtime library to open an input stream to the item in a zip file.

2:: Add the jar file as a searchable item

Configure a `StreamManager` - the classpath loader is there by default and you can add a `LocatorZip`

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/stream-manager.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try that!